# Obtener Dato del Registro con c#, duda al publicar

Tags: vb.net

Tengo una duda, estoy trabajando con una aplicación que toma valores de RegEdit, esto lo hace bien y con el siguiente comando:

```
Dim Bodega = CInt(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AvanWeb", "Cod_Bodega", Nothing))
```

Si yo lo hago correr de forma local, desde el visual studio me captura el valor y lo puedo usar, pero al momento de compilar y publicar, si esto lo monto en un IIS no me está capturando el valor y eso que lo estoy probando en el mismo equipo.

¿Estoy fallando en algo?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Ha configurado el ApplicationPool?

Comment: No, desconozco el tema pero voy a buscar información. puede ser ese el porqué no me toma la variable?

Comment: [Aquí un poco de documentacion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) cualquier duda si no logras configurar formulare una respuesta.

Comment: ok, lo voy a revisar a la tarde y comento. gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se trata de un problema de permisos, el sitio en el IIS ejecuta impersonando un usuario, el cual por lo general no tiene acceso a mucha funcionalidad de la pc que actua como servidor web

Para poder ejecutar la accion puedes cambiar este usuario de dos formas:

- Editando el usuario del `Application Pool`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el `identity` defines un usuario que tenga permisos de mofificar la registry

- Usando el `web.config` agregando el tag de `identity`

  `<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />`

en este puede definir que impersone definiendo un usuario y password que tenga permisos para la operacion que necesitas realizar

Comment: para dar un poco más de contexto a lo que necesito, esta ruta del regedit la tienen muchos equipos y cada uno tiene un valor diferente. Como es una app que corre por el lado servidor, creo que me convendría usar el tag por lo que pones, y para el caso tendría que poner el usuario administrador?

Comment: Pero el registry solo se ve afectado en el servidor, no en los clientes, es codigo .net el que ejecutas, no javascript. No importan los valores de los clientes.

Comment: ya, traté con el web.config
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="Administrador" password="miclave"/>
Pero al cargar la página me tira un error de que el usuario o clave no coresponden, afecta el orden?

Comment: mm es raro si defines correctamente el usuario y password, lo que no recuerda es dentro de cual tag en el web.config valida sino debe estar dentro de `<system.web>`

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, esta duda la voy a formular como una nueva pregunta