# Cambiar Identidad del IIS para acceder a dato de registro

Tags: iis

Tengo una aplicación que está generada en asp.net con visual basic la cual mediante una consulta obtengo un dato del registro, en mi pregunta anterior ([es esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279068/obtener-dato-del-registro-con-c-duda-al-publicar)) estaba preguntando si estaba accediendo bien pero me dijeron que ese no era el problema de fondo,sino que el IIS debe ir con un usuario que tenga acceso al registro de la maquina. Esto modificando la identidad del IIS.

Esto lo hice de forma local y me funcionó, pero tengo la duda de cómo tendría que ser en mi servidor que tiene el IIS.

Dando un poco de contexto esta aplicación corre en 20 equipos. Son cajas de un supermercado y en cada una, en el registro tiene el dato de a qué bodega (Cod_bodega) está asociada la caja, cada una tiene su propio usuario en donde corre la página y todos comparten el mismo usuario y clave de administrador.

La consulta que yo hago al registro es esta:

```
Bodega = CInt(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AvanWeb", "Cod_Bodega", Nothing))
```

y mi consulta es, al poner la identidad del administrador va a ir al *HKEY_CURRENT_USER* del administrador a buscar los datos o lo va a buscar al registro del usuario?

También tendría que crear el usuario administrador por el lado del servidor?

Quería saber si alguien me puede guiar un poco con esto, si le ha pasado lo mismo.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Porque guardas el usuario unico en el regitsro y no en la configuracion de tu sitio o un archivo de tu paquete de distribucion?

Comment: creo que no entendí bien la pregunta, pero ese dato que voy a buscar al registro cambia para cada equipo y en base a este valor se hacen consultas a una base de datos

Comment: Sera dificil, que puedas administrar usuarios de este modo, porque para cada instralacion el administrador debe dar permisos de lectura al registro al pool donde se este ejecutando tu sitio Y eso es peligroso, darle permisos de lectura escritura  al registro a una aplicacion web. No tienes otra manera de administrar los usuarios? digamos que ellos se registren?

Comment: no estoy muy seguro ya que yo no realicé la implementación de está página. pero estaba pensando en alternativas, quizás crear u archivo txt o ini y ahí poner las variables para ir a buscarlas. Esto se puede hacer con asp? o en realidad con visual basic

Comment: que version de asp.net es? los usuarios los puedes guardar en el archivo de configuracion cuando no son muchos. Y si ya estas usando una base de datos lo puedes realizar en la base de datos en lugar de leer el registro solo lees la base de datos de la tabla usuarios que tu crees.